# Collaborative album on Facebook

Tags: facebook, photos, photo-sharing, album

Is there any way I can let specific people add photos to my album on Facebook? The way it is, right now; If I have some photos of an event and my friend has some; then we need to collate before either of us creates a complete album.
Tagging helps to some extent. Still..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the [Groups Facebook App](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=2361831622), create a new group, (fill out the info, etc), on the screen after you fill out your group info, you'll see a lot of permissions. One which enables Photos and allows you to control who uploads photos to it. Click the box which says something like `"Only allow Admins to edit photos"`. Finish your group, add your friend as an admin and you should be set.

Comment: Also, don't forget to invite the people to join the group.

Comment: So there's actually no way to collaborate with just an ordinary fb page. To allow people to contribute photos, I need to create a separate group!

Comment: I can't say authoritatively, but **as far as I've seen**, this is your best (and only) bet.

Answer (score 0):

Use google picasa web albums. It has the ability allow others to contribute photos.

http://picasaweb.google.com

Comment: I need to use Facebook albums. How about all those people who aren't on Picasa and only see the FB feed.

Comment: use picasa for a while, then upload the album to FB when you're done

Comment: Does Picase let you upload directly to FB? I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. This sounds like it will add an extra layer of complexity to the privacy settings. People will need to authorize access to photos ... What happens if one person does not like what the other has posted ? Who has control over it ? What will be the version control ? I like the idea but I do not see it happening in the near future.

---

If the event is listed as a Facebook Event, it is still accessible even though the event is archived.

Select `Events` in the sidebar then `Past Events`
Scroll to the event.

Now from here there are two ways to do this

1. Be appointed as an admin (Say in the case where you have photos to add in batches)
2. Post a single photo at a time to the Event's wall

Pre-Facebook design change one was able to scroll to past events since 2008, I am not able to vet if this is still possible. So you will want to do it to recently archived events. I know for some people they use Past Events as spam.

Now the reasons why I think this is best for your scenario

- Provides all those who have attended with highlights of the event.
- Attendees are able to add and tag photos ( removing the need for authorization and admin appointment)